# How to hide a div for 24 hours with a cookie

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, show-hide

I need to hide this `div` for 24 hours. `put` it's not working.

I would like a simple JavaScript code that will allow me to hide a certain `div` element when clicked for a predefined amount of time.
To be a little more informative, I have a suggestions box that appears when the home page is loaded. What I would like is when the `div` close button is clicked, it sets a cookie to keep the box `div` closed for 24 hours (1 day).
Simply said, when the `div` close button is pressed, the box div is hidden for 24 hours.

Note: I have a javascript code that allows the close button to close the box but it will re-load every refresh.
[Link to the project's file](https://upload.aradev.net/do.php?id=30) *(Editor comment: it's not secure to download files from untrusted websites, it's better to wait for the author to edit the question with the code.)*

Comment: Please insert your code to your question!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]  - you cannot just paste a link to your site: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: You need to persist that on back-end to make it really resistant. If it is not so important, then persist it via cookie or local storage in a way that you store username, time clicked  and what to hide, some identificator.

Then your application needs to load this and check for surrently logged in user what it should show or not. And if timer expired remove from "memory" those that shoudl no longer be there to clean after itself.

Comment: this is the file
https://upload.aradev.net/do.php?id=30

Comment: A good question at Stackoverflow has the code in the body of the question.  Not links to other places.  This is because links will expire and then the question will and answer will not be of value to other people.  Please put the code (not a link to the code and not a screenshot) in the question.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. As @StephenM commented, code is necessary to answer questions on this website. Uploading a file is not a good way to do that, because it will expire and few people are willing to risk and download it. I've edited your question to make it more understandable, please do the same with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You All The Currect Code IS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // If the 'hide cookie is not set we show the message
  if (!readCookie('hide')) {
    $('#applink').show();
  }else {
    $('#applink').hide();
  }

  // Add the event that closes the popup and sets the cookie that tells us to
  // not show it again until one day has passed.
  $('#playstorclose').click(function() {
    $('#applink').hide();
    createCookie('hide', true, 1)
    return false;
  });

});

// ---
// And some generic cookie logic
// ---
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else var expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
  createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

```html
<div class="playstorapp" id="applink" style="text-align: center;margin: auto">
        <a id="playstorclose" href="JavaScript:void(0)">X</a>
        <a class="applink" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aradev.net&rdid=com.aradev.net" target="_blank">
            Download
        </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I noticed `#splashscreen` is set to be visible by default. You can either hide it by default and show it only if the cookie is **not present**. Or even simpler to add an `else statement` and hide it if the cookie is present. Please change the first `if statement` of your JS code as below.

```
// If the 'hide cookie is not set we show the message
  if (!readCookie('hide')) {
    $('#splashscreen').show();
  } else {
    $('#splashscreen').hide();
  }
```